# Ogre Projector shines through objects

Tags: c++, ogre, projector, decal

In Ogre, i'm projecting a decal onto a sphere. However, the decal shines straight through the sphere and projects another decal onto the opposite side! How do I stop that?

```
material planets/Planet_Earth { 
  technique { 
    pass { 
      texture_unit { 
        texture earth_surface.png 
        filtering trilinear 
        scale 1 1 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

I'm afraid neither of the below answers are working. I have tried every shadow setting ald explored blender's texture settings, but nothing seems to work. The decal just renders both sides! It even happens in Ogre Tutorial 6! Any possible suggestion appreciated!

Note: I'm editing someone elses code, and just discovered that it's not a mesh, the sphere is being created in the code :O sowwy :(

Comment: Can you provide the material script and a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: Sure :3 the material is:

material planets/Planet_Earth
{
   technique
   {
      pass
      {
         texture_unit
         {
          // texture earth.jpg
   // texture earthmap1k.jpg
    texture earth_surface.png
    filtering trilinear
    scale 1 1
         }
      }   
   }
}

I'm not allowed to post a pic though

Comment: You can edit your question adding more info, do not use comment for this. If you cannot post a picture, you can upload it somewhere (imageshack, dropbox...) and provide a link.

Comment: Is the "sphere" a mesh or a PT_SPHERE? Look at [this blender tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/UV_Map_Basics), it explains how uvmap works.

Comment: Thanks :) It's a mesh :)

Lol sorry, "not allowed", i meant the company I am working for won't allow me to post a picture

Comment: Maybe this one will help you: [OGRE Forum - Projective decals (without the back-projected second decal)](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=123116)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just couldn't get it to work, as there is no uv map. I gave up and used a .mesh that looked like my decal and positioned it on the surface of the sphere instead. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling some form of shadows should fix it.  [Ogre Basic Shadows](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Basic%20Tutorial%202)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a texture that fit your mesh. Ogre uses UV mapping to map decals to meshes. Depending on what CG program you are using to create your 3d model, there are different ways to create it. [Look at this blender tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D%3a_Noob_to_Pro/UV_Map_Basics) for an example. You need also an [exporter](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=OGRE+Exporters) to get a `.mesh` file out of it.

Comment: The texture fits perfectly :\

Comment: Has your mesh a UV map? It doesn't matter if the texture fits in blender, you need the correct UV map. Try UV/Image editor in blender and see if you have a correct UV map.